# Search for specific key word and replace entire cell contents with something else in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc

I would like to be able to search for a specific word, lets say "House" in a calc sheet, and then replace the entire cell content with something else like "Car".

It is important to notice, that the Find & Replace function does exactly this, but only with the word searched for, not with the entire cell contents.

So if I have a cell with the following content:

```
wefjweoi House dee88wef 4
```

I want to search for "House" find this cell, and replace the cell content with lets say the word "Car".

So the cell will look like this:

```
Car
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute a **[`regex search`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions)**: In the `Find & Replace` dialogue, open `Other Options...` and enable `Regular Expressions`. Then, in the search field, enter `.*House.*`; replace with `Car`. Now, since the regex pattern matches the whole cell content containing `House`, the complete cell content is replaced by `Car`.

[image]